# mod_rewrite replace / with _

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Sure I'm just missing something obvious here, but I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1_$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Which I would like to rewrite /shop/basket to /shop_basket.php. Instead if I go to / I get and internal server error, and if I go to /shop/basket it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Take IV: No, Really, This Is It!

It turned out be easier than I thought to get rid of `[DPI]`. The final set:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1_$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Now is this acceptable? :-)

---

### Take III: The (Not-So) Final Solution

Ok, after *much* testing and banging-head-on keyboard, I finally came up with something satisfactory. I'm definitely keeping this one in case I ever switch back to Apache for some reason.

The lightbulb went off in my head when I broke the problem up into two parts: replace `/` with `_`; then, add `.php` at the very end. Here's what I finally came up with:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1_$2 [DPI,N]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

Now, as I mentioned above, the biggest thing was to split the two operations up. Once I did that, everything became much easier. The two `RewriteCond`s are really neat, because they allow you to access files by their usual names, even with all of this other rewriting going on.

I noticed that I was getting infinite path redirection (which Apache couldn't detect), like `shop/basket_checkout/basket_checkout/basket/checkout`; that's when I realized Apache itself was appending paths to the end of the replaced path! Thus `[DPI]` fixes that.

The extra `RewriteCond` in the second block should be obvious: it prevents infinite redirection (ie if `foo.php` is unavailable, no point in trying `foo.php.php`, etc).

Let us know how this works for you.

---

### Take II: Nice try, but no dice

Whoops, even simpler than I first thought. Change `[N]` to `[C]` and you're good to go. As the [documentation for `[N]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) says:

> **Be careful not to create an infinite loop!**

Which is exactly what happened here. ;-)
I nearly took down my test VM on the first try -- that was fun!

It does strange things, though, when the php file doesn't actually exist. I'll test some more.

Comment: Ah, thank you! However the DPI flag was only added in Apache 2.2.12 (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_dpi), and I cant get all the servers this needs to work on updated to that version. Any other possible workaround?

Comment: Haha! In the voice of Adam Sandler in The Wedding Singer: "…things that could've been brought to my attention yesterday!" ;-) Please update your original question with the minimum version number I can use, and any other surprises you might have for me, and I'll see what I can do!

Comment: Well I think I got it – please let me know if the fourth iteration works… :-)

Comment: Ha, sorry for not mentioning that, honestly didn't even occur to me. Anyway, solution IV works perfectly, thank you so much! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're most welcome! I'm glad it's working for you.